# How to keep vectors as "labelled" when merging data frames with merge or left_join?

Tags: r, merge, label, left-join, labelled-generic

I am merging data frames, one of which has labelled data. However, when the data frames merge the labelled vectors become numeric. How could I keep this from happening?

The following example shows the problem with mtcars:

```
library(haven)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(am = c(0, 1),
                 var = c("X", "Y"))

mtcars$cyl <- labelled(mtcars$cyl, c("A" = 4, "B" = 6, "C" = 8))

class(mtcars$cyl)
```

Here, the mtcats$cyl is "labelled".

```
mtcars <- merge(mtcars, df, by.x = "am", by.y = "am", all.x = TRUE)
#OR
mtcars <- left_join(mtcars, df, by = c("am"="am"))

class(mtcars$cyl)
```

Then mtcars$cyl becomes "numeric". I have also noticed that the same thing happens if you crop out a part of the vector, such as here:

```
x <- mtcars$cyl[2:6]
class(mtcars$cyl)
```

Here x is "numeric" too.

Comment: I can't reproduce the isssue `left_join(mtcars, df, by = c("am"="am"))$cyl %>% class
[1] "haven_labelled";
> class(mtcars$cyl)
[1] "haven_labelled"` assuming `labelled` is from `library(labelled)`

Comment: It turns out that once i uninstalled the package "lmerTest" the probalem went away. Interestingly, it did not appear as "haven_labelled" as @akrun says, but still, it stays as "labelled" now for me.

Comment: May be, some function from `lmerTest` masked the other function.  Not clear though

Comment: ok, I used `library(labelled)` instead of `haven`, thanks